# ASP.NET Membership provider for windows forms application

Tags: .net, winforms, asp.net-membership

How to implement Membership provider and use the logon model in windows forms application? or for office templates in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in ASP.NET membership provider is SQL-based so using in stand-alone desktop application seems to be inapplicable

Comment: why? desktop applications and web apps use SQL databases all the same.

Comment: @tenfour: if OP's app is a thick client - no problem, i was talking about stand-alone app without direct access to a database